# Necessity entity having method setId()?

Tags: php, oop, doctrine-orm, doctrine, getter-setter

Every entity in Symfony has a property `$id` and getters and setters for it, but I actually can't understand why do we need to have the setId method because we almost never call it directly.

I could think only one suggestion for using a `setId()` method. It's a situation when we need to replace data for one entity by another saving the id of the replaced entity, but I'm not sure if it isn't the degenerate case.

Could somebody explain to me the reasons why we should have this method in entities classes?

Comment: It's a function you can pretty much always leave out. Further, you could create yourself an AbstractEntity class which has the property + getter and use that as a base for all entities (subsequently allowing a `$entity instanceof AbstractEntity` check), could use an IdentifierTrait, which adds the same, etc etc. A few reasons to add it though: consistency with other getters/setters; IDE (PhpStorm & others) generated it and deleting it doesn't add anything either; using "make" (in Symfony) generated it (and deleting it doesn't add anything either). Up to you really.. (Assumes auto-increment id)

Answer (score -1):

We use getters and setters when we declare attributes as Private.
This rule is to guarantee that there will be no accidental change of property.